# Connecting 30 amps to another 30 amps

Tags: wiring

I'm installing a new window to type AC using a 30 amp double pole breaker and a 10 guage wire. Since I already have a 30 amps line that runs my existing AC, is it ok? to connect to the existing line with 30 amps with another 30 amps?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify - it's unclear right now what you propose to do. Generically, no, it's never OK to have two breakers connected to the same load. Is the existing breaker double-pole, or it's single pole now and you are asking about converting to double pole? Unclear. Are the wires in conduit, or are they cables?

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplate on the existing air conditioner, and the specifications of the new air conditioner for that matter?

Comment: I think the OP might be asking if it's OK to add a 2nd 30 amp outlet to the same circuit.  Not sure though. Clearly he can't "double up" on an existing circuit, but I doubt that's what he's asking.     If he's asking about adding a second outlet for a 2nd A/C unit, we'd of course need to know the loads of both.

EDIT:  Shoot, I just reread the OP and think that he IS trying to double up. NO WAY CAN HE DO THAT>

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- we'd need to know the loads to be sure here